# Timed memory tiles game. now works without timing

Tags: c++, linux, timed

I have done a memory tiles program but i want it to be timed, i.e, the user shoud be able to play the game only for 2 mins. what do i do?

Also in linux sleep() does not work, what should we use for a delay??

Comment: `sleep` works fine, you're probably using it incorrectly, but we can't see your code so we can't tell you how to fix it.

Comment: Just check the elapsed time in your main loop and then when it exceeds the limit you can break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I presume the game has a "main loop" somewhere.

At the beginning of the main loop (before the actual loop), take the current time, call this `start_time`. Then in each iteration of the loop, take the current time again, call this `now`. The elapsed time is `elapsed_time = now - start_time;`. Assuming time is in seconds, then `if (elapsed_time >= 120) { ... end game ... }` would do the trick.